# Feature to detect a reverse timeseries

Tags: time-series, feature-engineering

I have a multiclass timeseries classification problem with 11 classes. The class 0 is my negative class, and the classes 1~10 are the positives and they are generated (using some equations) based on the samples from class 0. Those timeseries are hourly measurements of energy consumption in kWh.

One of those positives classes (class 10 from the picture), is just the negative class (class 0) timeseries in the reverse order ([flip)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html).

Check this picture for example:

[image]

At first i was using only the timeseries itself as input to my model. Then, i added the mean value of the timeseries, and it increased the performance detection in some classes, but of course it does not help improve the detection of class 10. What feature I could add to help detect this kind of reverse timeseries?